# Bootstrap: how to use radio buttons below select as input-group-addon?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When a user selects a certain option in a select I want two radio buttons to appear in which they also need to make a choice. To highlight the fact that the radio buttons are related to the select I want them to appear as an `input-group-addon` below the select.

I can make a radio button appear as an `input-group-addon` to the right of a select ([fiddle here](http://www.bootply.com/28ZHiQjYLB)):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio">
    </span>
</div>
```

But how would I display an `input-group-addon` below it so that it can contain two radio buttons below eachother?

Answer (score 0):

If your end result is as shown in the image below ..

[image]

then the code will be like this..

```
<div class="input-group">
   <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
   </select>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
   </label>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
   </label>
</div>
```